# User profile in front-end

Tags: pages, users, front-end, profiles

I want every user to get a profile in the front-end of my website.
So I want to visit website.com/user/user-name and view all the information of this user. Is this somehow possible?

I would like to do this without a plug-in. All things I'll found on Google did include a plug-in like [Front-End Only Users](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-only-users/)..

Comment: In a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) use `<?php global $current_user; var_dump($current_user); ?>`. For example: `<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 different things to achieve this.

**URL Structure:**

Getting the URL in your desired format: http://website.com/**user**/username

By default, user's archive URL is something like this http://website.com/**author**/username

There is a plugin to change author slug, install this plugin and set the slug to **user**

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-author-slug/

[Note: I'm the author of this plugin]

**Displaying info:**

Customize your `author.php` file in theme directory and show specific information.

In this file, you can get any of information a user has.

To get a user's display-name, simply use `<?php the_author_meta('display_name' ); ?>`

Or to get his first name, use `<?php the_author_meta('first_name' ); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried finding my current author URL, but I'm not able to. I've added an author.php file and copied the author-bio.php from the twentyfiftheen theme, but while visiting /author/username I get an 404.. Do you know why?

Comment: Try http://your-wp-url/?author=1 where 1 is user's ID.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it slightly different. I have a similar case but I created a custom post type with a full custom structure on the profile of that user. Using ACF, I linked the user account to the post in the custom post file. That way you have full control over how the user profile is structured and whatever fields are needed.